# Desmarcar input do tipo radio

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5, input

Eu tenho dois `inputs` do tipo `radio`. Segue o código abaixo:

```
 <input type="radio" id="isgift0" name="isgift" value="0" class="arredondado" /> 
 <label for="isgift0">Teste 1</label>

 <input type="radio" id="isgift1" name="isgift" value="1" style="display: none;" /> 
 <label for="isgift1">Teste 2</label>
```

E eu tenho o seguinte código em `jQuery`:

```
$j('input[name=isgift]').click(function(){
    if($j('#isgift1').is(':checked')){
        $j(".gift-from").val(name_from);
        $j(".gift-to").val(name_to);
        $j(".mensagem-pedido").removeClass("divDisabled");
        $j(".box-gift").addClass("divActive");
        $j('#allow-gift-messages-for-order-container').show();
    }
    else if($j('#isgift0').is(':checked')){
        $j(".gift-from").val('Anônimo');
        $j(".gift-to").val(name_to);
        $j(".box-gift").removeClass("divActive");
        $j(".mensagem-pedido").addClass("divDisabled");
    }
```

Como são `ìnputs` do tipo `radio` e com os nomes iguais, somente se pode marcar um dos dois.Porém eu precisava de fazer algo a mais do qual não estou conseguindo. Queria que quando o primeiro `ìnput`,no caso com o `id=isgift0`, se ele estivesse marcado e o usuário clicasse no mesmo, ele fosse desmarcado. Queria fazer isso somente para esse input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com a função abaixo, apenas o primeiro `radio` é desmarcado ao clicar novamente nele (execute o teste e veja as mensagens no *console.log*. Cada click em um `radio` executa um bloco da função):

```js
function exibirGift(){
              $('#allow_gift_messages').attr('checked','checked');
              $('#allow_gift_messages_for_order').attr('checked','checked');
              $('#gift-message-whole-message').attr('disabled',false);
              //$j('#allow_gift_messages_for_items').attr('checked','checked');
              $('#allow-gift-message-container').show();
              $('#allow-gift-messages-for-items-container').show();
            }
            function esconderGift(){
              $('#allow_gift_messages').attr('checked',false);
              $('#allow_gift_messages_for_order').attr('checked',false);
              $('#gift-message-whole-message').attr('disabled','disabled');
              //$j('#allow_gift_messages_for_items').attr('checked',false);
              $('#allow-gift-message-container').hide();
              $('#allow-gift-messages-for-items-container').hide();
            }
             var checado = false;
            $('input[name=isgift]').click(function(){
              var check1 = 0;
              var name_from = $(".nomeb").val();
              var name_to = $(".nomea").val();
              var isCartaoAdicionadoPagina = $('#cartao_adicionado_radio_productId').val();
              var isCartaoAdicionadoVerificacaoMensagem = $('#cartao_adicionado_product_id').val();
              if($(this).attr('id') != 'isgift0'){
                checado = false;
                //      $j(".gift-from").val(name_from);
                //      $j(".gift-to").val(name_to);
                //      $j(".mensagem-pedido").removeClass("divDisabled");
                //      $j(".box-gift").addClass("divActive");
                //      $j('#allow-gift-messages-for-order-container').show();
                console.log("2 marcado");
              }else{
                if(!checado){
                  this.checked = true

                  //        $j(".gift-from").val('Anônimo');
                  //        $j(".gift-to").val(name_to);
                  //        $j(".box-gift").removeClass("divActive");
                  //        $j(".mensagem-pedido").addClass("divDisabled");
                  console.log("1 marcado");
                }else{
                  this.checked = false;
                  console.log("1 desmarcado");
                }
                checado = this.checked;
              }});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" id="isgift0" name="isgift" value="0" /> 
<label for="isgift0">Teste 1</label>

<input type="radio" id="isgift1" name="isgift" value="1" /> 
<label for="isgift1">Teste 2</label>
```

Comment: Infelizmente, não funcionou...

Comment: @MatheusPortela Realize o teste e veja as mensagens que aparece.

Comment: Quando eu clico para marcar, me retorna "1 marcado". Quando eu clico no `input` para desmarcar ele, também me retorna "1 marcado".

Comment: @MatheusPortela Então tem outra coisa errada no seu código. Veja essa imagem de como funciona: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrbKd.png

Comment: Aqui coloquei todo o código utilizado, juntamente com as funções que também chamo e da maneira que está, não funcionou. https://jsfiddle.net/vtLdgj34/

Comment: @MatheusPortela atualizei a resposta. O `var checado = false;`tem que ficar antes do listener `$('input[name=isgift]').click(function(){`

Comment: Sim, agora funcionou, muito obrigado por toda ajuda e atenção!

Comment: @MatheusPortela De nada amigo!

Answer (score 2):

Apenas a função de ativar/desativar o primeiro "input radio"

```js
$(function() {
    var check1 = 0;
    $('input[name=isgift]').click(function() {
        if($('#isgift1').is(':checked')){
           check1 = 0;
        }
        if ($('#isgift0').is(':checked')) {
            if(check1 != 0) { 
                $(this).prop('checked', false);
                check1 = 0;
            } else {
                check1 = 1;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" id="isgift0" name="isgift" value="0" class="arredondado" /> 
<label for="isgift0">Teste 1</label>

<input type="radio" id="isgift1" name="isgift" value="1" /> 
<label for="isgift1">Teste 2</label>
```

Agora "tentando executar" com o trecho do código reportado na pergunta:

```js
var $j = $;
var check1 = 0;
$j('input[name=isgift]').click(function(){
    if($j('#isgift1').is(':checked')){
        check1 = 0;
        $j(".gift-from").val(name_from);
        $j(".gift-to").val(name_to);
        $j(".mensagem-pedido").removeClass("divDisabled");
        $j(".box-gift").addClass("divActive");
        $j('#allow-gift-messages-for-order-container').show();
    }
    else if($j('#isgift0').is(':checked')){
        if(check1 != 0) { 
            $j(this).prop('checked', false);
            check1 = 0;
        } else {
            check1 = 1;
        }
        $j(".gift-from").val('Anônimo');
        $j(".gift-to").val(name_to);
        $j(".box-gift").removeClass("divActive");
        $j(".mensagem-pedido").addClass("divDisabled");
    }
});
```

```html
 <input type="radio" id="isgift0" name="isgift" value="0" class="arredondado" />
 <label for="isgift0">Teste 1</label>
 <input type="radio" id="isgift1" name="isgift" value="1" style="display: none;" />
 <label for="isgift1">Teste 2</label>
 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: O seu código está certo sim, porém, o que ocorre nesse caso, é que ele acaba nem checando o `input` e eu queria que ele pudesse ser checado e se caso o usuário clicasse no mesmo, ele fosse desmarcado.

Comment: @MatheusPortela eu revisei a pergunta várias vezes e percebi que a necessidade era diferente mesmo. Editado, obrigado por pontuar!

Comment: Samuel, dei uma olhada e aparentemente a sintaxe está correta, porém ainda não funcionou...

Comment: @MatheusPortela Falta botar o `$j`.

Comment: @DvD Coloquei o `$j`, mas mesmo assim não funcionou...

Comment: O que nao funcionou? O snippet do stackoverflow está fazendo algo diferente do que deveria?

Comment: @SamuelFontebasso O snippet do stackoverflow está funcionando corretamente, porém colocando isso em meu código, não funciona. O `input` é marcado, porém ele não desmarca.

Comment: @MatheusPortela não sei porque utiliza o jQuery com `$j`, talvez está eliminando o conflito com outra biblioteca. Contudo, editei a resposta com um exemplo direto sobre o código que deixou na pergunta. Se houver outro trecho que esteja em conflito com este não tem como eu saber..

Comment: @SamuelFontebasso Eu uso o jQuery com o `$j`, justamente como você disse no seu comentário, para eliminar conflitos com outras bibliotecas. Então, esse exemplo que você colocou eu já tinha feito ele, mas porém não funcionou também. E sobre o conflito, não há nada no meu código que possa fazer isso, ou que eu uso esses `inputs` novamente.

Comment: Marcar e desmarcar um `input` com o trecho de código que apresentou está ok. Volte, e comece a analisar cada passo, utilize console.log em tudo para verificar se cada ação é disparada. Imprima um texto no console javascript dentro do escopo da função disparada com click para saber se está capturando o click nos `inputs` depois um console.log dentro do teste se o input está marcado como `checked` ou não e, se existe algum erro no javascript antes desse trecho tudo é interrompido e não executa, veja isso também. Não tem segredo se algo não funciona você tem que encontrar onde está parando..

Comment: @SamuelFontebasso Agradeço toda a ajuda e atenção prestados por sua parte!

Answer (score 2):

Criei um *snippet* e compartilho aqui:

```js
// itera com método do Array para compatibilidade
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('[type=radio]'), function(radio) {
  radio.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var self = this;
    // obter elementos com o mesmo nome exceto o próprio e grava estado desmarcado
    Array.prototype.filter.call(document.getElementsByName(this.name), function(filterEl) {
      return self !== filterEl;
    }).forEach(function(otherEl) {
      delete otherEl.dataset.check
    })

    // grava estado baseado no estado anterior
    if (this.dataset.hasOwnProperty('check')) {
      this.checked = false
      delete this.dataset.check
    } else {
      this.dataset.check = ''
    }
  }, false)
})

// versão jQuery:
/*
$('[type=radio]').on('click', function(e) {
  $('[name=' + this.name + ']').not(this).data('check', false)
  if ($(this).data('check')) this.checked = false
  $(this).data('check', this.checked)
})
*/
```

```html
<label><input type="radio" name="foo" value="1"/>foo = 1</label><br/>
<label><input type="radio" name="foo" value="2"/>foo = 2</label><br/>
<label><input type="radio" name="foo" value="3"/>foo = 3</label><br/>
<br/>
<label><input type="radio" name="bar" value="1"/>bar = 1</label><br/>
<label><input type="radio" name="bar" value="2"/>bar = 2</label><br/>
<label><input type="radio" name="bar" value="3"/>bar = 3</label><br/>
```